# Send adobeAirApp.ipa file to itunes connect

Tags: ios, air, flash-builder, app-store-connect, ipa

I finished creating my game using Flash Builder 4.7 and Adobe Air 3.8 (Gaming SDK 1.2) on Mac OS X 10.7.5

-- I exported my game for Android and game.apk file was generated, and I sent to Google Play (online now without problems) ...

-- I generated the certificate and provision of distribution.
I exported the game to iOS and game.ipa file was generated.
I downloaded the latest 2.8 Application Loader
But when I try to send my game via the "Open Package" in the Application Loader, my game.ipa is not evaluated for selection.

-- What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the app up in iTunes Connect and marked it as 'Ready to Upload Binary'?